# error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'. Error: you need to load the kernel first

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I have a Sony laptop and I had installed Ubuntu 1-2 months before. Suddenly when I opened my laptop, there is an error regarding grub rescue that says:

`error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'`

And

`error: you need to load the the kernel first`

I have reinstalled Ubuntu and again rebooted it and again I am getting this error. I tried to fix it so many times but nothing happened.

Please fix my issue.

Comment: Check your hardware for issues; as hardware problems (*or unsafe user behavior such as unclean shutdowns*) can cause metadata problems that can show as what you describe...   ie. Stop trying to re-install & ignore the problem, and explore what is causing it as what the *symptom* you're seeing actually means.  We're limited as you've provided no Ubuntu product/release details & cannot rule out user procedural mistakes that can also cause it due to lack of detail.